# How to embed progress bar In Cgridview Column in Yii

Tags: php, yii, progress-bar, cgridview

as the title says, I'm embedding a CJuiProgressBar inside a CGridView column using the following syntax:

```
array (
  'name'=>'cantidad_mails',
  'value'=>'$this->grid->Controller->createWidget("zii.widgets.jui.CJuiProgressBar",array(

    "value"=>intval($data->porcentaje),
    "htmlOptions"=>array(
      "style"=>"width:80px; height:20px; float:left; background-color:#44F44F ;background:#EFFDFF",
      "color" => "red"
    ),
  ))->run()',
),
```

And it's working fine the first time the page with the grid is loaded, but if I click on one of the pagination links of the grid, the progress bars disappear from the column.

Anyone know how to fix that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that grid pagination is made via ajax, so after ajax update progress bar is not reinitialized.

The most simple solution is to disable ajax updates, which are anyway [not efficient](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/163/avoiding-rendering-entire-page-when-using-cgridview-and-clistview-via-ajax/).

You can do this by setting `ajaxUpdate` of your grid config to `false`.

Option #2 is to reinit your progress bar by configuring `afterAjaxUpdate` option of your grid. [Here are docs regarding `afterAjaxUpdate`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail)